# How to fix the compile error using dynamic_cast in Android?

Tags: android, c++, g++, dynamic-cast

1. I am working on MTK platform with Andoird 4.4 kk.
2. Build Environment Check Result Report

[OS]: Ubuntu 10.04.4 (64-bit) [OK]

[Physical Memory Size] : 8079280 K-Bytes [OK]

[make]: 3.81 (64-bit) [OK]

[perl]: 5.10.1 (64-bit) [OK]

[python]: 2.6.5 (64-bit) [OK]

[arm-linux-androideabi-gcc]: 4.7 (64-bit) [OK]

[gcc]: 4.4.3 (64-bit) [OK]

[jdk]: 1.6.0_33 (64-bit) [OK]

[bison]: 2.4.1 (64-bit) [OK]

[flex]: 2.5.35 (64-bit) [OK]

[gperf]: 3.0.3 (64-bit) [OK]

[mingw]: Installed [OK]

[unix2dos/tofrodos]: Installed [OK]

1. code

(1)
    RecordClient.BufOps.cpp:

```
...
RecBufManager mpImgBufMgr;
mpImgBufMgr.init();
...

// Here is what I want to do
sp<ICameraImgBuf> pImgBuf = mpImgBufMgr->getBuf(1);
sp<RecImgBuf> pRecImgBuf = dynamic_cast<sp<RecImgBuf> >(pImgBuf);
```

(2)

```
class RecImgBuf : public ICameraImgBuf {

public:
    virtual                         ~RecImgBuf();
}
```

(3)

```
class RecBufManager : public RefBase
{
public:
    sp<ICameraImgBuf>const&         getBuf(size_t index) const  { return mvImgBuf[index]; }

private:
    Vector< sp<ICameraImgBuf> >     mvImgBuf;
}
```

(4)

```
bool
RecBufManager::
init(){
...
RecImgBuf* pRecImgBuf = RecImgBuf::alloc(...);
mvImgBuf.push_back(pRecImgBuf);
...
}
```

(5)

```
class ICameraImgBuf : public IImgBuf, public ICameraBuf
{
};
```

Then I got the Error:
mediatek/platform/mt6592/hardware/mtkcam/v1/hal/client/CamClient/Record/RecordClient.BufOps.cpp: In member function 'bool android::NSCamClient::NSRecordClient::RecordClient::handleReturnBuffers(const android::Vector&)':
mediatek/platform/mt6592/hardware/mtkcam/v1/hal/client/CamClient/Record/RecordClient.BufOps.cpp:325:68: **error: cannot dynamic_cast 'pImgBuf' (of type 'class android::sp') to type 'class** android::sp' (target is not pointer or reference)

When I delete the following code:

```
sp<RecImgBuf> pRecImgBuf = dynamic_cast<sp<RecImgBuf> >(pImgBuf);
```

it works fine.

How to fix the error ? Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

1. I simply the thought the android's sp is equal to the pointer. so I changed the code :

   ```
   sp<RecImgBuf>& pRecImgBuf = dynamic_cast<sp<RecImgBuf>& >(pImgBuf);
   ```

the new error :

error: cannot dynamic_cast 'pImgBuf' (of type 'class android::sp') to type 'class android::sp&' (**source type is not polymorphic**)

Even through I add the virtual method into the source type ICameraImgBuf, like this:

```
class ICameraImgBuf : public IImgBuf, public ICameraBuf
{
public:
    virtual                         ~ICameraImgBuf(){}
};
```

Comment: What is sp in sp<RecImgBuf>?

Answer (score 0):

dynamic_cast works only on pointers or references

Comment: I simply thought the sp in android is equal to the pointer. I am wrong about this.

Comment: I update the code : sp<RecImgBuf>& pRecImgBuf = dynamic_cast<sp<RecImgBuf>& >(pImgBuf); , but the new error:error: cannot dynamic_cast 'pImgBuf' (of type 'class android::sp<android::MtkCamUtils::ICameraImgBuf>') to type 'class android::sp<android::NSCamClient::NSRecordClient::RecImgBuf>&' (source type is not polymorphic)

Comment: even though I add the virtual ~ICameraImgBuf(){} into the source type (ICameraImgBuf)

Comment: You need to add virtual to class ICameraImgBuf

Comment: In fact, I had added.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.